Direct Peer IP, Next Hop Latency is Different based on the destination
I’m experiencing a network issue with one of my BGP peers, and I need some help understanding the root cause.
Notes: Public IPs i provided is random just to describe the issue
I have a BGP peer for the Middle East region with the next hop set to 192.168.100.1.
My advertised source prefix to this peer is 203.0.113.0/24.
My users, however, are assigned IPs from the 203.0.114.0/24 range.
Traffic destined for most Middle East prefixes works fine, but one specific prefix is experiencing high latency (~100ms) when traced.
The latency (100ms) consistently appears at the next hop IP, 192.168.100.1.
What I've Checked So Far:
The routes for the destination prefix appear correct in my routing table.
BGP Configuration:
My peer confirms they are accepting the advertised prefix (203.0.113.0/24), but I suspect there might be source-based policies or filtering at their end.
My Questions:
Could the issue be caused by the traffic originating from a source (203.0.114.0/24) for that specific prefix? so the source is not part of the advertised prefix and causing that?
How can I confirm whether the peer has any source-based policies or filtering in place?
Are there specific tools or methods on my router to verify the source IP used for traffic to this problematic prefix?
Any other troubleshooting steps I should take to isolate the issue further?

"How can I confirm whether the peer has any source-based policies or filtering in place?" You must ask the peer network administrator. Remember that questions about networks you do not directly control are off-topic here.

thanks for clarifying, i asked because i wanted to know if my source wasn't advertised will it cause this issue or not. because i configured my router to make traffic related to ME prefixes i added, be sourced with the advertised route itself.
so if this happening because of the difference in source from the adv. then the issue is within that case. so i needed help from someone having more experience in this or give me ideas to troubleshoot, because i couldn't confirm that at all, i don't know how and why only this prefix.
